# Long-running upload techniques

Tags: ios, file-upload, background-process

I have an application that will be uploading large files in the background on iOS (e.g. DropBox style).  What are some different techniques to keep the uploads moving?  So far I have:

1. Receive callbacks from the background networking service (NSURLSession), and resume a limited number of times (since the callbacks decrease in frequency)
2. Resume uploads when the app opens
3. Resume uploads when the location changes (which seems to be what DropBox does)

Are there any other techniques to ensure that background uploads complete?

Comment: Try this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-background-transfer-service--mobile-20595

Comment: I'm not so concerned about the background upload service itself, more the techniques to keep the large uploads moving over a period of hours.